# Ambari Host registration aborted

Tags: hadoop, ambari

### there is error log

ambari-agent is not running. No PID found at /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid

### Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'localhost:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server

Is there a problem with my configuration ?

Comment: Are the ambari-agent and ambari-server running on the same node? From the error message it's apparent that the agent thinks it is. If they are on the same host make sure ambari server is up and running. The following command should tell you if its running: sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Ambari server is running, the message suggests the Agent while startup is not able to connect to the Ambari server.

Answer (score 0):

As ambari agent is talking to localhost:8080 it will only work if your ambari-agent and server are on the same node, if not you will have to update ambari-agent.ini file in the node and change the hostname to the ambari-server host value.
If the error still persists update your /etc/hosts files in the master and the slave node to have fqdns of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Start ambari-server on the master, after that  ambari-agent should be started individually on all the nodes.